# How to change the location of the emergence of AdMob interstitial to start the application

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

How to change the location of the emergence of AdMob interstitial to start the application
Admob interstitial appears when you click on the camera icon
This is contrary to the policies of Admob
I want to make it appear within the application a way that is contrary to the policies of Admob

[This is what happens now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MTXd.jpg)

[I want to make it in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ2Us.jpg)

This is my GameOverscreen code.

```html
package com.package.name;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import picture.profile.logo.football.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class LauncherActivity extends Activity{

 private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2;
 private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
 public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
 public static int imageFrom = 0;
 protected static Uri outputFileUri = null;
 public static String selectedImagePath;
 private Uri fileUri; 
 // directory name to store captured images and videos
 private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";

 ImageView btnstart,img_more,img_rate,img_camera;

 private AdView mAdView;
 private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
 
 TextView txtname;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
  btnstart=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.start);
  img_camera=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_camera);
  img_more=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_more);
  img_rate=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_rate);
  txtname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_appname);
  Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "molten.ttf");
  txtname.setTypeface(font);
  
  
  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewad);
  mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

  mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(LauncherActivity.this);
  mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
  mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

  mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAdLoaded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAdLoaded();
    if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
     mInterstitial.show();
    }
   }
  });

  btnstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_PICK,
      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    i.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImagePath);
    startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PICTURE);
   }
  });
  
  img_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
   }
  });

  img_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String appName = getPackageName();//your application package name i.e play store application url
    try {
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
       Uri.parse("market://details?id="
         + appName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
     startActivity(new Intent(
       Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
       Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
         + appName)));
    }
   }
  });

  img_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_more_apps))));
   }
  });

 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
   Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
   int k=0;
   if (selectedImage != null)
   {
    try
    {
     k = getFileSize(selectedImage);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
     Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "unsupported media file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return;
    }
   }

   if (selectedImage != null && k != 0)
   {

    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
      filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    Log.e("path", selectedImagePath);
    startActivity(new Intent(this,ShapeSecondActivity.class).putExtra("imagePath", selectedImagePath));
   }
   else
   {
    Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this, "unsupported media file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  }
  if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    // successfully captured the image
    // display it in image view
    selectedImagePath=fileUri.getPath();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,ShapeSecondActivity.class).putExtra("imagePath", selectedImagePath));
   } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    // user cancelled Image capture
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   } else {
    // failed to capture image
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }
  }

 }



 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
  return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
 }

 /*
  * returning image / video
  */
 private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

  // External sdcard location
  File mediaStorageDir = new File(
    Environment
    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
    IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

  // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
  if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
   if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
    Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
      + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
    return null;
   }
  }

  // Create a media file name
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
  File mediaFile;
  if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
   mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
     + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
  }   else {
   return null;
  }

  return mediaFile;
 }

 private int getFileSize(Uri uri)
 {
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
  int i = cursor.getColumnIndex("_size");
  cursor.close();
  return i;
 }

}
```

Thank You

Comment: Looks like you are actually doing it as on the second screenshot... Showing the interstitial right after app launch. Could you define your problem better?

Comment: I got this message from admob
`Interstitial ads that appear before the app has opened or after the app has closed.
Interstitial ads that are triggered after a user closes another interstitial ad.
Interstitial ads loading unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content. Remember to only serve interstitials between pages of content.
Interstitial ads that trigger after every user click.
Interstitial ads that appear during periods of game play or heavy user interaction`
How do I make Admob interstitial Admob does not violate the policy?

Comment: I see. Then the only thing you are missing is the "App loading..." screen before launching your LauncherActivity :)

Comment: I did not understand you mean I am very weak in English :D
If you understand what I mean I wish I could find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interstitial ad is showing right after the app launches and it's against AdMob policy.

If I understand correctly, you want to show the interstitial when the user clicks the camera icon. Then, remove this from your `onCreate()`:

```java
mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAdLoaded();
        if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitial.show();
        }
    }
});
```

And change your `img_camera` click listener to this:

```java
img_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitial.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to make Admob interstitial appears after the introduction of the image to the application, not when you click on the camera icon or gallery

Comment: the `mInterstitial.show();` is the line that shows the interstitial. You can put it anywhere you want. If you want interstitial after user picks the photo from the gallery or camera, I suggest putting this line somewhere in your `onActivityResult()`.